# CSS Tooltip Closes When Moving from Trigger Element to Content with Gap

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue with CSS tooltips where the tooltip closes unexpectedly when moving the mouse from the trigger element to the tooltip content, especially when there is a gap or space between the two elements. The tooltip is triggered to appear on hover over the trigger element, but I want it to stay open when the mouse moves between the trigger and the content area.

I've tried adjusting the positioning and using :hover states, but the tooltip still disappears in this specific scenario. Is there a way to prevent the tooltip from closing when the mouse is between the trigger and content elements?

I tried to add `background-image: linear-gradient(green, green); (color could be changed to transparent)` to prevent tooltip content closing but it is not a good solution since i need a padding/margin to cover the space between trigger and content elements, but it adds a space between trigger element and rest of the text in the section as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.trigger-element {
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(green, green);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  /* padding: 20px; */
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.trigger-element:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

.tooltip-content .content {
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quod
      adipisci, ratione, iusto neque alias tempora, asperiores vero nam
      molestiae consequatur enim facere eius? Veniam ducimus non temporibus
      laborum nostrum.
      <span class="trigger-element">Hover me
        <span class="tooltip-content">Tooltip content</div>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to use padding instead of margin so you can remain hovering in your parent during the time you move your mouse to the tooltip content.

Below I have added an extra span for the tooltip styling and the initial tootip has the position and padding

```css
.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.trigger-element {
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(green, green);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  /* padding: 20px; */
  position: relative;
}

.trigger-element:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}


.tooltip-content > span {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display:block;
}

.tooltip-content .content {
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quod
      adipisci, ratione, iusto neque alias tempora, asperiores vero nam
      molestiae consequatur enim facere eius? Veniam ducimus non temporibus
      laborum nostrum.
      <span class="trigger-element">Hover me
        <span class="tooltip-content"><span>Tooltip content</span></span>
      </span>
    </div>
```